# Invoke a command like a user

Tags: discord.py

I have a command that I would like to invoke as if a user has entered the command in discord, but I'm lost on how to achieve it.

I want to invoke it as a user to use the `after_invoke` decorator because doing `await self.first(msg)` doesn't allow me to use the `@first.after_invoke` decorator. Is there a way to do this?

```py
class Bots(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,client):
        self.bot=client


    @command()
    async def first(self,msg):
        await msg.send("OK")

    @first.after_invoke
    async def first_after(self,msg):
        return None


    @command()
    async def second(self,msg):
        await self.first(msg)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Bots(bot))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sudo command, which might come in handy for you. However you should really explain your issue further and provide some examples for what you've tried as I don't fully understand your question here. Hope this helps!

```py
@checks.is_owner()
@commands.command(hidden=True, description="Force a user to run a command")
async def sudo(self, ctx, user: discord.Member, *, command):
    message = ctx.message
    prefix = await self.bot.get_prefix(message)
    message.author = user
    message.content = prefix + command
    await self.bot.invoke(await self.bot.get_context(message))
```